# Set buildconfigfield value from firebase remote config?

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-remote-config

I am facing problem while assigning value to buildconfigfield from firebase remote config . It always said val cannot reassigned. Searched on internet but not find any suitable solution of doing this task. All settings are working from firebase side. Value is coming but not assigned to variable. What I done so far is below.

Here is how I declare variable in build.gradle file:

```
buildConfigField "boolean", "enableMaintenceMood", "false"
```

Code to fetch value from remote config

```
 private fun maintenanceMood(){
        val remoteConfig = Firebase.remoteConfig
        val configSettings = FirebaseRemoteConfigSettings.Builder()
            .setMinimumFetchIntervalInSeconds(60)
            .build()
        remoteConfig.setConfigSettingsAsync(configSettings)

        val defaultValue = BuildConfig.enableMaintenceMood
        remoteConfig.setDefaultsAsync(mapOf("enableMaintenceMood" to defaultValue))
        remoteConfig.fetchAndActivate()

        remoteConfig.fetchAndActivate().addOnCompleteListener { task->
            if (task.isSuccessful){
                val myvar = remoteConfig.getBoolean("enableMaintenceMood")
                print(myvar)
                //here myvar give me value which I set in remote config
                BuildConfig.enableMaintenceMood = myvar
                //here is problem part val cannot be assigned error
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(this,"Something went wrong",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Please write proper sentences, end them with `.` etc.